# When Switching Scenes in Unity objects 100x in amount

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm new to coding games and using Unity, when I switch Scenes in unity the [objects 100x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdIE6.png) and [the saturation gets weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uLKH.png)

Here is my current script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    
public class Game_End : MonoBehaviour
{
    int Pins = 0;
    
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Pins += 1;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Pins == 4)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 2", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Unity! There are a few issues I can see, so I will try to explain each one. The main issue you are currently having is you are loading a scene on top of itself using the `LoadSceneMode.Additive`. It is loading the scene `Level 2` on top of itself as long as `Pins` is equal to 4, which I am guessing is every frame.

I would instead put this check inside of the `OnCollisionEnter` as it should only be called once. Your other issue is you are not checking what you are colliding with. You might want to check the object you hit by tag. If you are unfamiliar with tags, you can look at the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html). Adding a tag to your game called `Pins` and adding it to all of your objects that are pins will help resolve what you are colliding with.

Now to solve the near infinite amount of scenes you are spawning. As I mentioned, it is because your conditional check is in `Update`, which in Unity is called every frame. With the condition you are currently checking for, if pins is not reset, it will keep loading your scene. As you are also using the `Scene.Additive`, it will load the new scene on your old scene, so the variable `pins` will not reset unless you collide with something else. I would recommend changing your code to this example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Game_End : MonoBehaviour
{
    int Pins = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // we are only checking if the object we hit is tagged as 'Pins' to make sure we hit a pin
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Pins")
        {
            // add to the pins
            Pins += 1;
            
            // destroy the pin we hit so the player can not hit it twice
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            
            // check our condition to load the new scene
            if(Pins == 4)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you are only checking if the collision is with an object tagged as `Pin`, the counter will only go up when you collect a pin. By adding the `Destroy`, you assure that each pin will only increase the count by 1. And finally, by putting your level check inside of this function, it will only check your condition when it increases the count. My one question is, do you want to use `LoadSceneMode.Additive`? It loads a scene directly over your current scene. I believe you'd want to load the scene normally so it loads your new scene. Would you mind clarifying how you want to load the new scene a bit more? In my example snippet I removed the additive as I believe you do not want to use it. The docs Unity has for `LoadScene` use it, so I assume you got it from there.

If you do not understand any of what I said, feel free to ask any questions in the comments. I can tweak the answer as needed to help you understand.

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much this was very helpful and it works. I was using LoadSceneMode.Additive because I found it in some documentation on the unity website. Also thank you for explaining why you were putting certain lines in so I know what to do in a different situation.

Comment: @JudeCarroll Anytime! Glad I was able to help out. I also notice you are newer to StackOverflow - so Welcome! I would check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to become accommodated with how the site works. If you feel that this answer solved your problem, you can select the check mark to the left of the answer to close your question.